# Try to continue quiz after wrong answer

Tags: android

[Demo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEyT3.png)

I try to make a firebase quiz application project.It work's good but when i press the wrong button then it was hang and didn't work for next.
my code is here:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mCountDown.cancel();
    //still have question in list
    if (index < totalQuestion) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.list_question.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {
            score += 10;
            correctAnwer++;
            showQuestion(++index);
        }
        txtScore.setText(String.format("%d", score));
    }
}
```

After right answer it will go this method:

```
private void showQuestion(int index) {
    if (index < totalQuestion) {
        thisQuestion++;
        txtQuestionNum.setText(String.format("%d / %d", thisQuestion, totalQuestion));
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressValue = 0;
        if (Common.list_question.get(index).getIsImageQuestion().equals("true")) {
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(Common.list_question.get(index).getQuestion())
                    .into(question_image);
            question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            question_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            question_text.setText("Q. "+Common.list_question.get(index).getQuestion());
            question_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            question_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        btnA.setText(Common.list_question.get(index).getAnswerA());
        btnB.setText(Common.list_question.get(index).getAnswerB());
        btnC.setText(Common.list_question.get(index).getAnswerC());
        btnD.setText(Common.list_question.get(index).getAnswerD());
        mCountDown.start();
    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Done.class);
        Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
        dataSend.putInt("SCORE", score);
        dataSend.putInt("TOTAL", totalQuestion);
        dataSend.putInt("CORRECT", correctAnwer);
        intent.putExtras(dataSend);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

}
```

But after wrong answer it didn't work.I need to a condition for that but don't know how can i write code for **else** condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this logic checks if the user has clicked the correct answer button:

```
if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.list_question.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {
    score += 10;
    correctAnwer++;
    showQuestion(++index);
}
```

Now, you only want the `score` and number of correct answers (`correctAnwer`) to change if the correct answer is picked (i.e. go inside the `if` statement), but you *always* want to show the next question regardless of if the answer is correct or not. The easiest way is just to move `showQuestion` outside of the `if` statement like so:

```
if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.list_question.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {
    score += 10;
    correctAnwer++;
} 

showQuestion(++index);
txtScore.setText(String.format("%d", score));
```

Though if you do want to perform additional actions on an incorrect answer before moving to the next question, you can use an `else` statement like so:

```
if (clickedButton.getText().equals(Common.list_question.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {
    score += 10;
    correctAnwer++;
    showQuestion(++index);
} else {
    // Do stuff that only needs to be done for an incorrect answer 
    showQuestion(++index);
}

txtScore.setText(String.format("%d", score));
```

Comment: I try to using else condition for optimize.like if that's wrong than all button change their color and continue for next.Is it possible sir?

Comment: I've added an example of an `else` statement, you'll need to put the second `showQuestion()` inside of the click listener for your Continue button though, if you're not skipping to the next question straight away.

Comment: Is it possible to set button for skip question and previous too?

Comment: You should be able to using more `else if` statements in that block. However, that's probably outside the scope of this question now, so give it a try and if you get stuck feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)